# How to pull all headings textContents out of HTML and make a <ul> list out of them?

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild

For a blog I want to create a side navigation bar which will pull all blog post titles (written in `<h2>`'s) and list them inside a `<ul>`.
Here's what I have so far, but for some reason it puts all the headings textContents into a single `<li>`, instead of creating separate `<li>`'s per heading.
Can anyone tell why? I can't figure it out for some reason...

[js.fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xkgvm7d6/1/)

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  var ul = document.getElementById("sideNav");
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var h2 = document.getElementsByTagName("h2");
  for (var i = 0; i < h2.length; i++) {
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(h2[i].textContent));
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
})
```

```html
<h2>Header 1</h2>
<h2>Header 2</h2>
<h2>Header 3</h2>
<h2>Header 4</h2>
<ul id="sideNav"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only creating a single `li` element, but you need one for each headline. Move the line

```
var li = document.createElement("li");
```

inside the loop and it will work.

Comment: I knew it would be something simple, but I was completely blind to it... Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

You only ever create one LI

Since you use fat arrows, why not use the selection and forEach

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const ul = document.getElementById("sideNav");
  [...document.querySelectorAll("h2")].forEach(h2 => {
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(h2.textContent)); 
    ul.appendChild(li);
  })
})
```

```html
<h2>Header 1</h2>
<h2>Header 2</h2>
<h2>Header 3</h2>
<h2>Header 4</h2>
<ul id="sideNav"></ul>
```

or map:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.getElementById("sideNav").innerHTML =  [...document.querySelectorAll("h2")]
    .map(h2 => `<li>${h2.textContent}</li>`).join("");
})
```

```html
<h2>Header 1</h2>
<h2>Header 2</h2>
<h2>Header 3</h2>
<h2>Header 4</h2>
<ul id="sideNav"></ul>
```

Comment: This looks more concise! Thanks!
Also, thanks to you I've learned that they call them "fat arrows"... thank you :D